# How coroutines can be faster than threads?

Tags: multithreading, performance, kotlin, coroutine

I am trying to find a situation where changing multithreading to coroutines will speed up processing of the affected code section. As far as I discovered that coroutines use less CPU and Heap space comparing to threads, I still can't find the case where coroutines are faster than threads. Although I know that coroutines creation and context-switching are much cheaper than corresponding operations with threads, I've got imperceptible results in speed difference (without measuring thread creation both cases will be absolutely the same).

So, is it even possible to find a case where coroutines will faster an execution more than threads?

Comment: One thing to note is that coroutines are vastly superior when you have lots an lots of them. You can create and execute thousands of coroutines without a second thought, if you attempted to do that via threads all the overhead associated with threads might quickly kill the host. So, this enables you to think about massive parallelization without having to manage worker threads and runnables.

Comment: @Robin please post it as an answer

Comment: @Ilya Done, also added a bit more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing to note is that coroutines are vastly superior when you have lots and lots of them. You can create and execute thousands of coroutines without a second thought, if you attempted to do that via threads all the overhead associated with threads might quickly kill the host. So, this enables you to think about massive parallelization without having to manage worker threads and runnables. They also make it easy to implement asynchronous computation patterns which would be very unwieldy to implement with basic threads, like channels and actors.

Out of scope regarding your question, but still noteworthy is the genericity of the concept, as the use cases for coroutines are not just limited to asynchronous computation. The core of coroutines are suspendable functions, which for example also enables generators like you have in python, which you would not immediately connect to asynchronous programming.

Comment: I agree with you that coroutines have more advantages than threads, but I thought they also should be a bit more faster because of threads context switching or some another heavy operations. I was just curious if it's viable to change some working part of the multithreaded code to coroutines opt for increasing speed.

Comment: @Praytic Well, on the speed side, the improvements should be the more noticable, the more asynchronous tasks you have, and the smaller those tasks are by themselves. So if you're doing some large download on a background thread, you won't see much improvement speedwise by switching to coroutines, since the actual thread overhead is still tiny compared to the operation.